# Function pointer, was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I use function pointer

```
MyWSARecvProc OriginalWSARecvProc = (MyWSARecvProc) WSARecv;
```

Function WSARecv is declared in winsock2.h:

```
WINSOCK_API_LINKAGE int WINAPI WSARecv(SOCKET,
    LPWSABUF, DWORD, LPDWORD, LPDWORD, LPWSAOVERLAPPED,
    LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE);
```

I include winsock2.h in my file, but there are error:

> error: 'WSARecv' was not declared in this scope

Why does it happen? How to fix it?
Thanks.

**edited**

I include winsock2.h before windows.h as Adrian Ratnapala writed. Now I have other errors:

```
src\netredirect.o:netredirect.cpp:(.data+0x18): undefined reference to `WSARecv@28'
src\netredirect.o:netredirect.cpp:(.data+0x1c): undefined reference to `WSARecvFrom@36'
src\netredirect.o:netredirect.cpp:(.data+0x20): undefined reference to `WSASend@28'
src\netredirect.o:netredirect.cpp:(.data+0x24): undefined reference to `WSASendTo@36'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a(main.o): In function `main':
e:\p\giaw\src\pkg\mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src\bld/../mingwrt-4.0.3-1-mingw32-src/src/libcrt/crt/main.c:91: undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of `MyWSARecvProc`? **EDIT** I googled your code, and found that this is code you're likely using from online. Did you do `#include "common.h"` which defines `typedef int (WINAPI *MyRecvProc) (SOCKET s, char *buf, int len, int flags);`? This is the link where I found your code: here http://clemgalerie.free.fr/Documents/Divers/Bot%20ragna/openkore-wx-1.6.1/src/auto/XSTools/win32/netredirect.cpp and here http://clemgalerie.free.fr/Documents/Divers/Bot%20ragna/openkore-wx-1.6.1/src/auto/XSTools/win32/common.h

Comment: Can you use other symbols from `winsock.h`?  This link seems to be relevant http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/winsock2.h%20include%20order

Comment: AndyG, definition of MyWSARecvProc u can see in your links. Yes, I include common.h.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite explicit. WSARecv is not known at the point you use it. Either move the function definition before its first use, or add a declaration before its first use.

Answer (score 0):

If to you seem that the function is in the scope,just try to move it like a global function and see what happen.(Don't leave it there,just see if the problem is really because it's out of the scope)